# Fighting answer plagiators

Tags: discussion, answers, plagiarism

This happens way too often, there is some trivial question, many people answer in few seconds, and then they compete in polishing the answers to win the booty.

That's OK, but problem arises when one answer is originally good and quite detailed, and the other answerers gradually copy stuff from it (be it code, ideas, useful remarks) and incorporate it in their answers.

So, how does one defeat his answer in this situation? Flagging is not possible since the unoriginal answers are not bad quality. Downvoting is wrong for the same reasons.

Comment: Don't answer trivial questions and if you do, accept that there are plenty of people who want easy rep like you.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I don't mind them answering the same or similar, but I *do* have a problem with them copying my answer.

Comment: Why are you so convinced they copied your answer? Trivial questions means most people know the answer.

Comment: When I see their one-liner grow to add things that are in my answer all along, it certainly raises some suspicion, don't you think?

Comment: It can raise anything it want, fact remains that you clearly stated the question is trivial so it is assumed many people know the answer. Maybe you type faster and wait a little longer to submit than others but that doesn't mean they didn't know it themselves.

Comment: There may be nothing that can be done. Unless it's 1:1 plagiarism, there is no way to tell whether they stole from your answer, or simply gradually arrived at similar results by themselves.

Comment: Not something I'd actually recommend, but if you can't beat them then join them.  You too can post a quick non-detailed answer and work to embellish it later.  Do keep in mind that this is in general not a strategy that will keep you interested in SO for very long.  It gets boring in a hurry.

Answer (score 7):

In short, you can't "defeat" anything and there's no magic formula for a winning answer, let alone answer that is protected from being "copied".

Your base assumption is wrong: usually (can't say always) when the question is simple enough, it's common that many users give the same answer, each on his own. Been there done that, never plagiarized a different answer or seen my own answer really being plagiarized.

Just give the best answer you can, watch for comments asking to clarify and that's it. No need to dwell in there looking how others respond or suspecting others for stealing your ideas.

Of course if you see someone doing a complete copy&paste of your (or anyone's else) answer as-is with variable names and everything it's a different story, in such case just flag, explain as "other" and it will get deleted at some point.